# How to display a selected record in a textbox

Tags: c#, mysql

So I'm trying to put selected records from my table into the textboxes, more specifically, the user's first name and their ID.

textBox2 displays the first name and textBox3 displays the ID. Technically, it works, but it always displays the LAST records from the table, not the specific records that the user used to login.

Example, textBox2 displays "Bob" and textBox3 displays "2", when supposedly they should be displaying "Bill" and "1".

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
void login()
    {
        string firstName;
        string studentID;

        string path = "Data Source = LOCALHOST; Initial Catalog =library ; username='root';password=''";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(path);
        string sqlSelect = "select * from users";
        MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlSelect, con);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    firstName = sqlReader["FirstName"].ToString();
                    studentID = sqlReader["ID"].ToString();
                    textBox2.Text = firstName;
                    textBox3.Text = studentID;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Code for logging in the first form.

```
void login()
    {
        string userName;
        string password;
        string userType;

        string path = "Data Source = LOCALHOST; Initial Catalog =library ; username='root';password=''";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(path);
        string sqlSelect = "select * from users WHERE Username = '" + textBox1.Text + "' AND Password = '" + textBox2.Text + "'";
        MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlSelect, con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    userName = sqlReader["Username"].ToString();
                    password = sqlReader["Password"].ToString();
                    userType = sqlReader["UserType"].ToString();

                    if (textBox1.Text == userName)
                    {
                    if (textBox2.Text == password)
                        {
                            if (comboBox1.Text == userType)
                            {
                                if (userType == "Admin")
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Logged in as Admin", "Login");
                                    Admin frmAdmin = new Admin();
                                    this.Hide();
                                    frmAdmin.Show();
                                }
                                else if (userType == "Student")
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Logged in as Student", "Login");
                                    Student frmStudent = new Student();
                                    this.Hide();
                                    frmStudent.Show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Do you have a UID for the current user? How do you know who is currently logged in?

Comment: No, I don't. That's the problem I guess, I don't know how to find out who's currently logged in. How do you do that?

Comment: Why are you closing your connection in the `catch` block?  Constructive criticism.  I would suggest you move `con.Close();` into a `finally` block instead.  Otherwise, `Close()` is only called if there is some exception.

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting all users from the table. You need some WHERE logic to limit that result set to 1 row. Otherwise your while loop will iterate until the last record returned, and those will be the values displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting all users data on your query

```
string sqlSelect = "select * from users";
```

when you should get only the one from the user that logged in, e.g.

```
string sqlSelect = "select * from users WHERE id=<ID of user logged in>";
```

The while loop is overwriting/updating the textBox2 and textBox3 with the information of each user on the table, so when it finishes it's always on the last user.
So, if you get only the user logged in, the information will be correctly shown.
Hope I helped.

Comment: Yeah, this definitely helps, but I don't know how to get the current user's ID. The way I'm doing it, the first form is the login page and then it goes to the second form. How do I get the current ID from the first form?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# but,
maybe you even don't need to do the second SELECT.
In the first form, after the user enters the username and password you check if it's correct by doing a `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=<username entered by user> AND password=<password entered by user>`, isn't it?

If the sqlReader used in the first form is still available (as I said I'm not familiar with C#) you can get the data from there instead of using another SELECT. If not you can, on the first form get the Name and the ID on a Public variable and in the second form just show them in the textBoxs.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding TextBox values over and over again until you reach the last one. If you just want to show the first record in the text box use this query:

```
string sqlSelect = "select TOP 1 * from users";
```

*And write column names instead of *. It increases the query speed*

If you are searching for a specific user, try:

```
string sqlSelect = string.Format("select * from users where username={0}",username); //supposed the login-ed user name is saved in username
```

Or

```
string sqlSelect = string.Format("select * from users where id={0}",userId); //supposed the login-ed user id is saved in userId
```

**Update**

For keeping username and other information use a `public string` and use it in all the forms you need. You can initialize it in a separate class:

```
public static string Username;
```

Comment: How do I do that by getting the username from the first form? The first form is the login form, so that's where username gets saved, but I can't call username into the second form. I edited my post with the code I used for the login.